Generate database migrations from spring boot entity with mvn liquibase:diff but changeSets count: 0
I try to generate database migrations from spring boot entity with mvn liquibase:diff but changeSets count: 0
here is my pom file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ch.Liquibase</groupId>
<artifactId>Liquibase</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Liquibase</name>
<description>Liquibase</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.30</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.24.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.24.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/config/liquibase-development.properties</propertyFile>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>true</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
 </build>
</project>

here is my liquibase-development.properties
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-diff-changeLog.xml
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-new-changeLog.xml
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase_demo_db
defaultSchemaName=liquibase_demo_db
username=root
password=123456

driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

referenceDefaultSchemaName=liquibase_demo_ref
referenceDriver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase_demo_ref
referenceUsername=root
referencePassword=123456
liquibase.generateChangesetCreatedValues=true
liquibase.pro.sql.inline=true
liquibase.includeCatalogInSpecification=true
liquibase.command.diffChangeLog.format=xml
liquibase.command.diffChangeLog.skipDatabaseStep=true

here is my application.properties
 ## Database Properties
# Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase_demo_db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 123456

# Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

# LIQUIBASE (LiquibaseProperties)
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.liquibase.default-schema=my_schema
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_schema
spring.liquibase.enabled=true

here is my entity model
    package com.example.demo.model;

import com.example.demo.model.ModelEntity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "customers")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address;


}

here is my application file
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

when i run  mvn liquibase:diff
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-latest.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd"/>

got this message
changeSets count: 0
[INFO] No changesets to add.

i have tried various way but not changeset generated
hope someone will help me for this issue
Thanks in advance

By any changes do you have the following message in your logs: "Diff changelog command failed" . If so check your diffChangeLogFile as it may be poiting to an invalid location and Liquibase is surpressing the error log (to be fixed in liquibase 4.28.0 ) .

@Lautert
i have tried using liquibase 4.28.0 but still same issue but thanks for your comment

But 4.28.0 hans't been released yet, it may be released until the end of this month :)

I see your liquibase-development.properties file has the url and referenceUrl point to 2 databases. and the liquibase:diff goal will compare source (referenceUrl) and target (url) and found no differernces between theses.
But your goal is to generate the changelog from the Entity class, right? Because I see you stated in your post is I try to generate database migrations from spring boot entity
